# Binding to RotateTransform in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a `DataTemplate` for my list items which looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
    <Grid Height="60">
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="88"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="310"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="72"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image MaxHeight="48" MaxWidth="40" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="1"/>

            <ContentPresenter x:Name="AnimatedIndicator" Grid.Column="2" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
                <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="/Assets/Images/arrow.png" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Width="30" Height="30" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform x:Name="AnimatedIndicatorRotate" Angle="{Binding IsRotated, Converter={StaticResource IsRotatedToAngleConverter}}"/>
                </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
            </ContentPresenter>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

My problem is that the binding in the `RotateTransform` does not work, and the converter does not get called.
So when I animate the angle with a storyboard, after some scrolling because of the virtualization the angle is reset, and binding to the IsRotated property should fix this, but it does not work.

Comment: Is the property IsRotated inside the all object of the list ?

Comment: It is in every object of the list, I receive NO binding errors in the output window

Comment: Your Name is correctly bindinded ? Try to display IsRotated as a string in a TextBox to see if you access the property. With only this sample of code I can only guess.